# What settings are needed to prevent 504 Gateway Time-out when deleting all products?

Tags: magento2, timeout

I am deleting all products in my magento 2 system.
There are about 1200 products in my catalog.

When I select all and delete, after 60 seconds I get a 504 Gateway Time-out on Nginx.

What are the recommeneded settings in this case?

Comment: Try raising max_execution_time setting in php.ini

Comment: I set that to `600` it still timesout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here was ensuring varnish did not timeout with:

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
  .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}
```

As described in the [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html)

Then it was ensuring the nginx and php-fpm did not timeout. Ensure to add:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
```

on both ssl and non-ssl servers