# Getting Gateway Time out error in backend for Configurable products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

When i click on Edit or delete for Configurable Products in Backend i am getting error like

GateWay Time out Error

Website also loading slowly

For reference please find the attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trick here was ensuring varnish did not timeout with:

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
  .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}
```

As described in the docs

Then it was ensuring the nginx and php-fpm did not timeout. Ensure to add:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
```

on both ssl and non-ssl servers

And more refer

[What settings are needed to prevent 504 Gateway Time-out when deleting all products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161044/what-settings-are-needed-to-prevent-504-gateway-time-out-when-deleting-all-produ)

Comment: Mohit Patel We are using apache server where can i put these things ?fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;

Comment: try this :- 

upload_max_filesize:1000M
max_execution_time:18000
memory_limit:2048M
max_input_time:18000
max_input_vars:3000
post_max_size:1000M

And restart the apche and mysql